# How to train new data continuously in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I use TF-slim training flower data set, scripts is [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/scripts/finetune_inception_v3_on_flowers.sh). the flower data set has only 5 classes. If I add some new image data to the roses, or add a new classification, what should I do after the train 1000 steps? Do I need to delete already trained data, such as checkpoint files?

Answer (score 4):

There exists a similar question on [Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12761/should-a-model-be-re-trained-if-new-observations-are-available), with an answer that considers your scenario:

> Once a model is trained and you get new data which can be used for
>   training, you can load the previous model and train onto it. For
>   example, you can save your model as a .pickle file and load it and
>   train further onto it when new data is available. Do note that for the
>   model to predict correctly, the new training data should have a
>   similar distribution as the past data

I do the same in my own project, where I started with a small dataset that grew bigger over the time. After addding new data I retrain the model from the last checkpoint.